# How can I show registration form inside modal?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show registration form inside modal popup. Now I can use fancybox and show modal popup but how can I show registration form of wordpress inside that modal? Is there any plugin available for it or it we can do it in Wordpress itself?

Preferably, it would be great if even captcha is available in that plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin, However it hasn't updated since 2 years but it works fine, i just tested for you.

[Registration Form on Modal popup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/modal-register/)